# Can't boot into or mount Mojave APFS partition after repartitioning for Linux

Tags: macos, partition, startup, mount, apfs

MacBook Pro 2015, 256GB SSD disk

I have created a second partition on my disk to try Linux. Everything was fine, but at some point, macOS disappeared from the boot menu.

After some googling and trying some things, I thought it was a problem with the boot manager. I installed [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) but it didn't help. So I tried torecover everything using recovery mode. But there was no option to reinstall macOS on the first partition. I could only erase it. I also couldn't mount it to macOS Recovery.

I installed OS X 10.10 Yosemite (base for my MacBook) on the second partition and updated it to macOS 10.14 Mojave (to be able to mount that first APFS partition). But I still can't mount it:

```
daniils-MacBook-Pro:Volumes daniilkk_yose$ sudo mount -t apfs /dev/disk0s2 plz/
mount_apfs: mount: Inappropriate file type or format
```

Also, diskutil outputs many `F`'s instead of type and name:

```
daniils-MacBook-Pro:Volumes daniilkk_yose$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2: FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF               129.2 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         121.6 GB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +121.6 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s3
   1:                APFS Volume disk1s3                 12.8 GB    disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 43.1 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                510.4 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk1s4
```

Disk Utility doesn't show this partition at all:

[image: Disk Utility]

Is there a way to mount it and get my data back?

Comment: Most linux installers have a command you can use to fix this sort of problem.

Comment: What kind of a command?

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too (3 times actually). I fixed it like this:

- Boot into a LiveCD containing fdisk or gdisk (I used gdisk so I can’t give fdisk instructions)
- Type `gdisk /dev/sdX`, where X is your SSD. You can use `gdisk -l /dev/sd*` or `fdisk -l /dev/sd*` to find it. It’s the one with the partition with the FFFF spam.
- Type the following:

```
t
2
af0a
w
y
```

Explanation: `t` for "set type of partition", `2` for the second partition (disk0s2), `af0a` for "Apple APFS", `w` for write, and y to confirm.

- Reboot, you will be able to boot MacOS again.

Answer (score -1):

I've had exactly the same issue on an older MBP running 10.13.6.  I've tried twice to work around it and got your problem.

In the end (both times) I had to do a recovery using internet recovery (option-command-r) and then restore my stuff from Time Machine.
I looked at rEFInd but didn't install it, so I can't say how to drive it.

It seems that APFS doesn't like to be messed with.  I'm looking at dropping the APFS and just living with the old journaled FS as a fixed size partition.

After that, I figure I can tinker with the EFI partition until I get it right.